# Why does fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) return false

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to learn about PDO and while i am trying to return some values from database i keep getting false as return from my `var_dump($row)` and i can't figure out why.
This is my code

```
 require("db.php");
 $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM names");

        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        {
            echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "<br>";
            var_dump($row);
        }
```

The weird part is that when I do it like this it returns desired database records.

```
 foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM names") as $row){

            echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "<br>";

        }
```

Note: Yes i know i should be using prepared statements,but i haven't got to that part yet.

Comment: Note: There is no point preparing a query if it has not parameters

Comment: Okay, you got me there -.-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a typo caused by

```
//                                          ↓this                 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
{
    echo $row['name'] . " " . $row['surname'] . "<br>";
    var_dump($row);
}
```

The semicolon before the brace disassociates the loop from the code in the braces, and it runs through the result set without doing anything.

You end up with `false` when you `var_dump($row)` because you've already fetched the last row, then the next fetch returns false.

Comment: Ooo Eagle eyes :)